# Random Number From given numbers in C#

Tags: arrays, random, numbers

Random Number From given numbers in C#

I want to choose a random number from array contains set of numbers?

```
Random r = new Random();
int [] arr={1,5,12,25,14};
int randomNoCorss;
randomNoCorss=r.Next(arr[i]);
```

Comment: So where did i creep in from?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
randomNoCorss = arr[r.Next(arr.Length)];
```

Comment: i want the same number in the arr but choose only one random number

Comment: @AhmedSooft, that's what this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to say: OK I have 5 numbers.
Lets generate a random number between 0 and 1

`arr[0]` is <0.2
`arr[1]` is between 0.2 and 0.4
`arr[2]` is is between 0.4 and 0.6 and so on...

Enjoy your day.

Comment: i want the same number in the arr but choose only one random number